# How to add ObjectId to default [Array] in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How to add ObjectId to default [Array] in mongoose?
I have a schema below and I don't know how to automatically add ObjectID:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  course: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Course',
  },
  comments: [
    {
      id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      avatar: {
        type: String,
      },
      content: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your content'],
      },
      reply: { type: Array, default: [] },
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    },
  ],
});

module.exports =
  mongoose.models.Comment || mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

As you saw, how can I add ObjectID to **reply** when I save

This is my code to save reply comments:

```
const replyComment = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
  const commentModel = await Comment.findOne({ course: req.query.courseId });

  if (!commentModel) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler('Invalid course', 400));
  }

  const commentIndex = commentModel.comments.findIndex(
    (comment) => comment._id == req.query.commentId
  );

  if (commentIndex === -1) {
    return next(
      new ErrorHandler('No comments of the course was found with this ID', 400)
    );
  }
  console.log(commentModel.comments[commentIndex]);

  const data = {
    id: req.user._id,
    name: req.user.name,
    avatar: req.user.avatar.url,
    content: req.body.content,
  };
  let commentAfterSaved = null;

  commentModel.comments[commentIndex].reply = [
    ...commentModel.comments[commentIndex].reply,
    data,
  ];
  await commentModel.save().then((comments) => {
    commentAfterSaved =
      comments.comments[commentIndex].reply[
        comments.comments[commentIndex].reply.length - 1
      ];
  });
  commentModel.save();

  return res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    comment: commentAfterSaved,
  });
});
```

What I want is:

Each object in the Array of Reply must have ID :

```
{
      id: **ObjectID(this is what I want)**
      userID: '618ac07fa34206fa3698d920',
      name: 'Gia An',
      avatar: 'https://graph.facebook.com/674527979558467/picture?type=large',
      content: '123'
}
```

Thank you guys so much have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

finally I ended with this solution:

Manual add objectID

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

Then added in:

```
  const data = {
    id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    userId: req.user._id,
    name: req.user.name,
    avatar: req.user.avatar.url,
    content: req.body.content,
  };
```

And then save it:

```
await commentModel.save()
```